# Share sqlite file via intent

Tags: android, sqlite, file, android-intent

In my app I want users to be able to make backups of their database so I provide an option to upload a db file to some cloud storage app via intent.

Here's my current code (in Scala) which does not work:

```
val intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent setType "application/octet-stream"

val file = getDatabasePath(AbstractKit.DB_FILE_NAME)
android.util.Log.d(TAG, file.exists.toString) // true

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getPath))
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
startActivity(intent)
```

File chooser gets started but none of the apps available actually accept a file saying it has a wrong format or a like. Why does it happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: You should copy your database to external storage and then send it, because applications can't access your application private storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Orest indicated in the comment, third party apps do not have access to your app's internal storage. `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` is for serving content via a `ContentProvider`, not for files.

You can use `FileProvider` along with `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` (see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider)). Or you can copy the database to external storage, then share that link. That would also give the user the ability to save the backup to their desktop or notebook.